# Add class to several elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a cloned element and I want it so if I add a class to one of them it checks for active removes is and adds it to this and translates to the other. Here's what I'm working with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $("li").click(function(){

        /*Here I want to add something like var active = $(.clonedelement + this, this)
        but that does probably not makes sense, so what should i do? */

        var active = $(this)

      // If this isn't already active
      if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
        // Remove the class from anything that is active
        $("li.active").removeClass("active");
        // And make this active
        active.addClass("active");

      }
    });


});
```

Right now, it removes the current active from both, not does only add class to one.

I made a jsfiddle of it
http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/8BxuE/

```
function UpdateTableHeaders() {
   $(".persist-area").each(function() {

       var el             = $(this),
           offset         = el.offset(),
           scrollTop      = $(window).scrollTop(),
           Header = $("#headerny", this)

       if ((scrollTop > offset.top) && (scrollTop < offset.top + el.height())) {
          Header.addClass("floatingHeader");
       } else {
          Header.removeClass("floatingHeader");

       };
   });
}
// DOM Ready      
$(function() {

   $(window)
    .scroll(UpdateTableHeaders)
    .trigger("scroll");

});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

[demo updated 1](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/8BxuE/1/)
[demo updated 2](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/8BxuE/3/)  //with clone(true)
[demo updated 3](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/8BxuE/4/)  //with clone(false) - default
[demo updated 4](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/8BxuE/5/)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', 'li', function(){
        var ind = $(this).index();
        $('li').removeClass('active');
        $('li').eq(ind).addClass('active');
        $('#header1').empty();
        $('#header').find('ul').clone(true).appendTo( '#header1' );
    });
});
```

Comment: It's still not adding it to the other element;live see the main navigation here http://richardhedberg.com/portfoliony/index.html

Comment: Thanks, but not really what I'm looking for. I'll try to explain, I have a header with a li and when scrolling down it duplicates and hides the first one. I need the active state to transfer between them. I'll add the cloning script to the initial post so you can see for yourself.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8BxuE/2/ here, i want the active state to be on both the headers, so when you click for example "work" on one, it should be active on both.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to highlight the clicked element with the class of active, and remove all others then try this:

```
$("li").click(function(){
    $("li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
```

You don't really need to check if either this, or others already have the class, simply steamroller to 'active' class off all the others and add it to the one that's been clicked

Comment: It's still not adding it to the other element;live see the main navigation here it clones it after it hits the top richardhedberg.com/portfoliony/index.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $("li").click(function(){
        $("li").removeClass("active");
        // And make this active
        $(this).addClass("active");

      }
    });


});
```

Comment: It's still not adding it to the other element;live see the main navigation here it clones it after it hits the top richardhedberg.com/portfoliony/index.html

Comment: if you want to add to the other,you can do this:$("li").click(function(){
    $("li").addClass("active");
    // And make this active
    $(this).removeClass("active");

  }
});

Comment: I suppose there's one bracket too much in the end there? This is almost there, however, its adds active to all li items in both elements except the one i click in the currently displayed one.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8BxuE/2/ here, i want the active state to be on both the headers, so when you click for example "work" on one, it should be active on both.

Comment: I think i know your mean, but I think you can only use one to display the header by changing the position

Comment: That's actually true, only problem is that it becomes super jumpy as it changes http://richardhedberg.com/portfoliony/index.html, i guess it has something to do with it triggering over and over again at a specific place. Do you know how to work around that? I added the script in the main post.